# Configuring a loopback interface on a Cisco router

Tags: cisco, router, ios, loopback

I have Router 1 with the following interfaces:

- FA0/1: 192.168.9.193 255.255.255.224
- S0/0/0: 192.168.9.129 255.255.255.224
- S0/0/1: 192.168.9.161 255.255.255.224

This is for my assignment at university, there should be a computer connected to the FA0/1 interface of this router, the computer should have these details:

- IP: 192.168.9.222
- Subnet: 255.255.255.224
- Default Gateway:192.168.9.193.

As I don't have a computer available to connect to the router I was told to use a loopback interface to virtualise this.

Please help me on setting up this loopback.

Comment: A loopback interface and an attached computer aren't the same kind of thing. What is the actual goal?

Answer (score 2):

Just do as you would do with a regular interface:

```
enable 
conf t 
int loopback 1
ip address 192.168.9.193 255.255.255.224 
no shut
```

Now enable routing for that subnet on your router and you are all set.

Comment: THE Ip used for FA0/1 is 192.168.9.193 255.255.255.224 says the loopback overlaps it....

Comment: Updated, sorry it's getting late, is it working ?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to disable the keepalive on the FastEthernet to artificially bring it up :

```
Router(config)# interface FastEthernet0/1
Router(config)# no keepalive
```

The interface will now show up/up even if there is no cable plugged on the interface. Therefore your router will be reachable from the wan on his Fa0/1 (192.168.9.193) IP address.